# Make transparent effect by nodes

Tags: shaders

I need a material for my leaf. I have an alpha texture but i dont know ho to make like a transparent effect( i dont know how to name it) [image]

how can i do like on a picture?

Comment: use a _**translucent shader**_ and plug your texture nodes into it's color

Answer (score 0):

If your image has a transparent alpha channel (which I assume) use the alpha output of your image node as the mix factor of whatever you want your leaf to be and a transparent shader (shader mix node). 
If not, there should be a black and white image in the leaf textures, use its color channels to mix the two.